# MySQL multiple items linked to one ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm making a Quiz and I have to tables: Questions and Answers.

http://pastebin.com/6UWF8RCy

I've got a problem with the sql-query

Now I get one JSONObject containing the Question for each answer, how can I get one object per question containing all the answers linked to that question? So when I read the json-data I can take the first object containing the first answer and the answers linked to that question.

EDIT: The php-code, the whole JSON-part doesn't matter, because if I get the array right then the JSON will be correct too.

```
$query = "
        SELECT * FROM Questions
        LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM Questions
        RIGHT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID
        LIMIT 10";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = $row;

}



$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Can you post your query? And maybe the PHP code you're using to generate the JSON?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nTt9KqP7 here is the array if people prefer that.
What I want is array([0]['answers']array([0] => answer1 [1] => answer2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure abt the query giving the correct result

you could just use

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Questions
            LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID ";
```

instead of the union, but with your query this should give what you are expecting..

```
$query = "
        SELECT * FROM Questions
        LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM Questions
        RIGHT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID
        LIMIT 10";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[$row['questionID']]['answers'][$row['answerID']] = $row['answer'];
        $array[$row['questionID']]['questionID'] = $row['questionID'];
        $array[$row['questionID']]['question'] = $row['question'];
        $array[$row['questionID']]['category'] = $row['category'];
        $array[$row['questionID']]['correct'] = $row['correct'];
}

$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Worked very good, I just made some slight changes since "correct" corresponds to the answer so I moved it. But thank you very much indeed!

Comment: But what if I use ORDER BY RAND(), then it doesn't work at all. Because I don't want to use the first questions every time, I want random questions, is there a way to solve it in the query or is the another solution? I could always print all the questions and chose random in the code but the when it starts being a lot of questions it will be slower, but maybe it doesn't get that slow since it's only text?

Comment: try this query                                                     $query = "SELECT * FROM Questions
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Answers ORDER BY RAND()) AS Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID ";

Comment: At the moment I'm using this: $query = "
        SELECT * FROM Questions
        LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID
        LIMIT 10";

And if I ad ORDER BY RAND(), I only get one answer per question.

Comment: this shud work then                                            SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 20) AS Questions LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID

Comment: Yeah that works :) But the problem is that the first position in every object is the same number as the questionID. I don't get them ordered 1,2,3,4 etc. Even if the questions are random I still want the arrays first position to be number from 0 so it will be easier reading it. And also, where do I put a WHERE clause? Because I tried to put WHERE questionID > 0 but I get an sql-error every time.

Comment: this should definitely work...........................................SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY RAND()) AS Questions ORDER BY questionID, answerID) AS Questions LIMIT 0, 20)   LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiasm but "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" on the latest query

Comment: I think I missed a couple of braces in that query....so there was error thrown.............chk this ......... SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY RAND()
   ) AS Questions ORDER BY questionID, answerID
  ) AS Questions
    LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID=Answers.questionID

Comment: use phpmyadmin or adminer or command shell ....take single subqueries and check them by executing....and then add the next level of query and again check....do so...you will get the error....although from my view this query shud be working

Comment: "Unknown column 'answerID' in 'order clause'", but I think you're misunderstanding me. http://pastebin.com/UchWHTK4 where I get the "12, 24, 27, 36, 37" I want "1, 2, 3, 4, etc"

Comment: Or no, I don't want that field at all, because if I get rid of it then I can parse JSONObject(0) to get the first question, JSONObject(1) to get the second etc etc

Comment: But if I do this: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array['questionID'] = $row['questionID'];
        $array['question'] = $row['question'];
        $array['category'] = $row['category'];
        $array['answers'][$row['answerID']]['answerID'] = $row['answerID'];
        $array['answers'][$row['answerID']]['answer'] = $row['answer'];

}

instead of the above, then I get one question with all the answers.